# If using jetson in edge computing what are the possible ways to send the collected data to main server

Tags: spring-boot, gps, cloud, ubuntu-18.04, nvidia-jetson-nano

If using jetson for example to track the real time location of a vehicle using a GPS module what are the best practices to send the collected GPS coordinates to the central server in real time. Should it be a webserver using rest apis or is there any other alternatives?

I want the data from the edge device to be sent to a spring boot application

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Jetson device for any other application?. What Jetson device are you using? I am not sure I understand your objective. I am assuming you have a computer vision application and you want to align each inference (Detection) with a GPS coordinate, is it correct?  Most GPS units use UART, Lets suppose you are using Jetson Nano.  Let me know if you need help connecting the module 9What GPS module are you using?). Now, let's say you are using Adafruit (Ultimate Breakout v3) GPS module.
On Jeston nano you can use the built in UART via

```
/dev/ttyTHS1
```

Wire the GPS as follows:

1-

1. Connect the Jetson Nano +3.3V pin to the Vin pin on the GPS.
2. Connect the Jetson Nano Ground pin to the GPS Ground pin.
3. Connect the Jetson Nano UART TX (#8) to the GPS RX pin.
4. Connect the Jetson Nano UART RX (#10) to the GPS TX pin.

The next step and for this specific example (GPS module), you need to install the Adafruit GPS CircuitPython library. Now that you have your GPS module installed properly, I strongly recommend to use Nvidia Deepstream, you should be able to use GPS data as part of the configuration file. Look at `gie-kitti-output-dir` (never done this but based on the documentation, I will assume that's the way).
[image: Deepstream architecture]
Deepstream has a specific plugins: The Message Converter `Gst-nvmsgconv` and Message Broker `Gst-nvmsgbroker` plugins in combination to send analytics data to a server in the Cloud. In my view it's the best way to do it, Deepstream provides some good example apps. I hope my answer will give you some ideas. Good luck.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation I am using a jetson nano and the gps module I am using is Ublox neo 8m. The application requirement is to detect the number of people in the camera feed and collect the gps coordinates of the location and send it to the spring server. Further without using the UART serial port can we get the gps coordinates from the USB Micro B port in the GPS module.